# How to fix 'TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function' from typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I'm setting up a server using TypeORM + PostgreSQL. When saving saving my entity to the entity's repository, I receive the error: `TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function` and the entity is not saved to the database.

This seems to only happen when I am using the `@OneToMany` or `@TreeChildren` decorators.

Here is my entity class that is causing the problem:

```js
import { ServiceData } from './service-data.entity';
import { ManufacturerData } from './manufacturer-data.entity';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, TreeChildren } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Advertisement {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name?: string;

  @Column()
  gatewayId: string;

  @Column()
  rssi: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  mac?: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  manufacturerData?: ManufacturerData[];

  @TreeChildren()
  serviceData?: ServiceData;
}
```

The (abbreviated) error output is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function
    at OneToManySubjectBuilder.buildForSubjectRelation (/<project-directory>/src/persistence/subject-builder/OneToManySubjectBuilder.ts:78:25)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem.

`@TreeChildren` and `@OneToMany` always expect an array. I had to change `serviceData?: ServiceData;` to `serviceData?: ServiceData[];`

Answer (score 4):

This error can come up when the oneTomany relationships are not properly written in the Entity design and also when you trying to store the relationships in a table.

The first One is, setting the Entity holding many of the other Entity like this

```
@OneToMany(() => Address, (address) => address.users)
address: Address[];
```

The other entity that has manyToOne relationship like this,

```
@ManyToOne(() => Users, (users) => users.address)
users: Users;
```

If the relationships are all good, then the problem is storing the entity relations to the database.

when creating the user, store the relationships like this

```
address = await this.addressRepository.findOneOrFail({
      
      where: {

        user_id: Number(userId),

      },

    });


const user = new User();

user.name = name;
user.age = age;

### store the address as an array of objects to the relationship column
users.address = [address]
```